# Передача ArrayList<String> в другой класс

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Пишу приложение на android, парсер новостей, с помощью библиотеки Jsoup.

В одном классе получаю ссылки и записываю в массив `Arraylist<String> linkList`, как мне потом получить значения `linkList` в другом классе (файле), методом `getLinkList()` не получается?

```
**MainActivity.java**

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private static MainActivity activity;

public static MainActivity getActivity() {
    return activity;
}

public RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;
public RecyclerView recyclerView;

public ArrayList<String> getLinkList() {
    return linkList;
}

public void setLinkList(ArrayList<String> linkList) {
    this.linkList = linkList;
}

public ArrayList<String> linkList;

Intent intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    activity = this;

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    try {
        setLinkList(new Article().execute().get());
        Log.d("myLogs", "linkList: " + getLinkList());
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}

class Article extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

    ArrayList<String> link = new ArrayList<>();

    Elements content;

    Document doc = null;

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... voids) {


        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("https://dev.by").get();

            content = doc.select(".article-preview__title__link");
            link.clear();
            for (Element links : content) {
                link.add(links.absUrl("href"));
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return link;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> stringArrayList) {
        super.onPostExecute(stringArrayList);

        //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "link_page: " + stringArrayList);
        recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(title, image);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
    }
}
}
```

класс RecyclerAdapter.java

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<String> title = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> image = new ArrayList<>();

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    CardView cardView;
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView tvTitle;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);

        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("myLogs", "onClickLink: " + new MainActivity().getLinkList());
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ArticleView.class);
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("link", new MainActivity().getLinkList());
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.getActivity(), "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
}

public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<String> title, ArrayList<String> imageViews) {
    this.title = title;
    this.image = imageViews;
}

@Override
public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.tvTitle.setText(title.get(position));

    Picasso.with(MainActivity.getActivity())
            .load(image.get(position))
            .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .into(holder.imageView);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return title.size();
}
}
```

класс ArticleView.java
    public class ArticleView extends ActionBarActivity {

```
ArrayList<String> linkList = new ArrayList<>();

TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.article_view);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    linkList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("link");

        Log.d("myLogs", "getLinkList in ArticleView: " + linkList);
}
}
```

Comment: Приведите код обоих классов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При запуске второй активити поместите ваш список в интенет так:

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("key", arrayList);
```

После, во второй актвити получите их из интента так:

```
List<String> list = getIntent().getStringArrayList("key");
```

Comment: дело в том, что у меня есть еще один класс RecyclerAdapter, в котором я обрабатываю нажатие, а значение ссылки я получаю в классе MainActivity. Я не могу понять как мне в  интент добавить данные класса MainActivity ArrayList<String> linkList

Comment: @nikolay, вопрос ваш не очень понятен. Вам надо из одной активти передать в другую список строк? Это в ответе есть. Теперь у вас в каждой активити есть список строк. Теперь вы можете брать его из любой активити

Comment: заранее извиняюсь за не понятные вопросы, просто только начинаю разбираться в Android, сейчас попробую добавить код

Comment: @nikolay, вот это в корне неверно `setLinkList(new Article().execute().get());` - вам надо присваивать полученный список переменной в onPOstExecute а не так.